# For positive reals $a,b,c$, prove or disprove $ab+bc+ca+abc\ge \sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> For positive reals $a,b,c$, prove or disprove $ab+bc+ca+abc\ge \sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}+1$

This is an intermediate step of another problem. Its not comming to my head. I have applied AM-GM and CS in all ways my brain can think of.

Comment: Hey! Do not downvote ths. I wrte prove or disprove, so it has been disproved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume $$a=b=c \Rightarrow 3a^2+a^3\geq 3a+1$$
Now take $a=\frac{1}{3}$ then
$$3\cdot\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{27}\geq 3\cdot\frac{1}{3}+1$$
which is not true, thus a counter example.

Answer (score 4):

Well, what happens to both sides if $a,b,c$ all become very small?

Comment: What do you mean by very small?

Comment: @amityas Say each of them is $\frac1{10}$. Or really, anything smaller than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should read $ab+bc+ca+abc\ge \sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}+1$.

Try $a=b=c=1/2$. Conclusion ?